# Android: View cut off when moved out of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view which can be moved on screen left and right. I am adding this view in a relative layout. Here is some of the code of my custom view:
The parent view of the SubtopicsView class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.androidstackedview.R;
import com.example.androidstackedview.views.BaseView.ViewState;

public class StackedView extends RelativeLayout {

    Context context;
    View dashboardView;
    TopicsView topicsView;
    SubTopicsView subtopicsView;
    DetailsView detailsView;
    float widthFactor = 10;
    public static int screenHeight;
    public static int screenWidth;
    public static float xDocked = 0;
    public StackedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public StackedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        initScreenDimenstions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        initColumnViews();
        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            topicsView.layout(dashboardView.getWidth(), 0, (int) (dashboardView.getWidth()+screenWidth/2 - screenWidth/2 * .30f), screenHeight);
        }
        else {
            topicsView.layout(dashboardView.getWidth(), 0, (int) (dashboardView.getWidth()+screenWidth/2), screenHeight);
        }
        topicsView.setxNormal(dashboardView.getWidth());
        topicsView.setxDocked(xDocked);
        if(!topicsView.isAnimating) {
            topicsView.changeState(topicsView.mViewState, false);
        }

        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            subtopicsView.layout((int) (topicsView.getLeft()+topicsView.getWidth()), 0, (topicsView.getLeft()+topicsView.getWidth()) + topicsView.getWidth(), screenHeight);
            subtopicsView.setxNormal(topicsView.getLeft()+topicsView.getWidth());
        }
        else {
            subtopicsView.layout((int) (screenWidth/2), 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            subtopicsView.setxNormal(screenWidth/2);
        }

        subtopicsView.setxDocked(xDocked);
        subtopicsView.changeState(subtopicsView.mViewState, false);

        //      detailsView.layout((int) (xDocked), 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        //      detailsView.setxNormal(xDocked);
        //      detailsView.setxDocked(xDocked);
        //      detailsView.changeState(detailsView.mViewState, false);
        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            detailsView.layout((int) (xDocked), 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            detailsView.setxNormal(xDocked + topicsView.getWidth());
            detailsView.setxDocked(xDocked);
            detailsView.changeState(ViewState.DOCKED, false);
        }
        else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            detailsView.layout((int) (xDocked + topicsView.getWidth()/2), 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            detailsView.setxNormal(xDocked + topicsView.getWidth());
            detailsView.setxDocked(xDocked + topicsView.getWidth()/2);
            detailsView.changeState(ViewState.DOCKED, false);
        }



    }

    public void initColumnViews() {
        if(dashboardView == null) {
            dashboardView = findViewWithTag("dashboard");

        }
        if(dashboardView != null) {
            View v = dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.testimg);
            if(v != null) {
                xDocked = v.getLeft() + v.getWidth();
            }
        }
        if(topicsView == null) {
            topicsView = (TopicsView) findViewWithTag("topics");
        }
        if(subtopicsView == null) {
            subtopicsView = (SubTopicsView) findViewWithTag("subtopics");
        }
        if(detailsView == null) {
            detailsView = (DetailsView) findViewWithTag("details");
        }
    }

    private void initScreenDimenstions() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    }

    public void resetTo1stPhase() {

        topicsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //      if(topicsView.mViewState == ViewState.DOCKED) {
        //          topicsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, true);
        //      } else {
        topicsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);
        //      }

        subtopicsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        subtopicsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);

        detailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        detailsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);

    }

    public void resetTo2ndPhase() {
        topicsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            topicsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);
        }
        else {
            if(topicsView.mViewState == ViewState.DOCKED) {
                topicsView.changeState(ViewState.DOCKED, false);
            } else {
                topicsView.changeState(ViewState.DOCKED, true);
            }
        }

        subtopicsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subtopicsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);

        detailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        detailsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);
    }

    public void resetTo3rdPhase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        subtopicsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subtopicsView.changeState(ViewState.DOCKED, false);

        detailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        detailsView.changeState(ViewState.NORMAL, false);
    }

    public void loadFragmentInTopicsFrame(Fragment f) {
        initColumnViews();
        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
        t.replace(topicsView.findViewById(R.id.fr1).getId(), f);
        t.commit();
        resetTo1stPhase();
    }

    public void loadFragmentInSubtopicsFrame(Fragment f) {
        initColumnViews();
        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
        t.replace(subtopicsView.findViewById(R.id.fr2).getId(), f);
        t.commit();
        resetTo2ndPhase();
    }

    public void loadFragmentInDetailsFrame(Fragment f) {
        initColumnViews();
        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
        t.replace(detailsView.findViewById(R.id.fr3).getId(), f);
        t.commit();
        resetTo3rdPhase();
    }
}
```

...........
This is the BaseView i.e. parent of Subtopics class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class BaseView extends RelativeLayout {

    float xNormal;
    float xDocked;
    float px;
    boolean isAnimating = false;
    public ViewState mViewState = ViewState.NORMAL;
    final float TOUCH_FACTOR = 0.60f;
    final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 100;


    public BaseView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(isAnimating) {
            return true;
        }
        if(mViewState == ViewState.DOCKED) {
            return true;
        }
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            px = event.getX();
        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            float newX = event.getX();
            float dx = newX - px;
            if(Math.abs(dx) > 0) {
                float value = getLeft()+(dx*TOUCH_FACTOR);
                if(value < 0) {
                    value = 0;
                }
                layout((int)(value), 0, (int)(value+getWidth()), getHeight());
            }

            px = newX;

        }
        else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            float toX = 0;
            if(mViewState == ViewState.NORMAL) {
                toX =xNormal-getLeft();
            }
            else if(mViewState == ViewState.DOCKED) {
                toX = xDocked-getLeft();
            }
            StackedAnimation anim = new StackedAnimation(this, 0, toX, ANIMATION_DURATION);
            anim.setListener(new OnHAnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    isAnimating = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onEnd() {
                    isAnimating = false;
                    changeState(mViewState, false);
                }
            });
            anim.start();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void changeState(ViewState state, boolean animate) {
        mViewState = state;
        if(mViewState == ViewState.NORMAL) {
            if(animate) {
                StackedAnimation anim = new StackedAnimation(this, getLeft(), xNormal, ANIMATION_DURATION);
                anim.setListener(new OnHAnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isAnimating = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEnd() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isAnimating = false;
                        layout((int) xNormal, 0, (int) (xNormal+getWidth()), getHeight());
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
            } else {
                layout((int) xNormal, 0, (int) (xNormal+getWidth()), getHeight());
            }

        }
        else if(mViewState == ViewState.DOCKED) {
            if(animate) {
                StackedAnimation anim = new StackedAnimation(this, getLeft(), xDocked, ANIMATION_DURATION);
                anim.setListener(new OnHAnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isAnimating = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEnd() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isAnimating = false;
                        layout((int) xDocked, 0, (int) (xDocked+getWidth()), getHeight());
                    }
                });
                anim.start();
            } else {
                layout((int) xDocked, 0, (int) (xDocked+getWidth()), getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    public float getxNormal() {
        return xNormal;
    }

    public void setxNormal(float xNormal) {
        this.xNormal = xNormal;
    }

    public float getxDocked() {
        return xDocked;
    }

    public void setxDocked(float xLocked) {
        this.xDocked = xLocked;
    }

    public boolean isAnimating() {
        return isAnimating;
    }

    public void setAnimating(boolean isAnimating) {
        this.isAnimating = isAnimating;
    }

    public enum ViewState {
        NORMAL,
        DOCKED,
        NONE;
    }

    public enum ColumnType {
        TOPIC,
        SUBTOPIC,
        DETAILS;
    }




}
```

......
And this is the Subtopics class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class SubTopicsView extends BaseView {

    StackedView stackView;
    Context context;
    private int screenHeight;
    private int screenWidth;

    public SubTopicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setBackgroundColor(0xFF888888);
        initScreenDimenstions();
    }

    public SubTopicsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setBackgroundColor(0xFF888888);
        initScreenDimenstions();
    }

    public SubTopicsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setBackgroundColor(0xFF888888);
        initScreenDimenstions();
    }

    private void initScreenDimenstions() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if(findViewById(R.id.parent) != null) {
            int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
            if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth/2 - screenWidth/2 * .30f), screenHeight);
            }
            else {
                params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth/2), screenHeight);
            }
            findViewById(R.id.parent).setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    }

}
```

The view moves properly on touch but when the view starts going out of the screen either on left or right side, it starts to cut off from other side as in the below screenshot. 
[image]
Any idea why the view is behaving like this?

Comment: could you show us your relative layout?

Comment: Its parent have nothing to do with this class because I am handling the touch event in the Baseview. I think the problem is within the onTouchEvent function.

Comment: you could have some kind of problem with the padding of your parent layout.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please have a look on it.